# VBA to extend multiple/all named ranges in a workbook

Tags: excel, vba, resize, extend, named-ranges

I am trying hard since last weekend to work with a code for extending ALL named ranges in a workbook, but it always gives error. Following is where I have reached so far, any help will be highly appreciated:

```
    Sub ResizeNamedRange()
    Dim xWb As Workbook
    Dim xName As Name
    Set xWb = Application.ActiveWorkbook
    Set xName = xWb.Names.Item
    
    For Each xName In ActiveWorkbook.Names

    With xName
        .RefersTo = .RefersToRange.Resize(, 14)
    End With
    Next
    End Sub
```

I have also tried the following code:

```
Sub AdjNamedRanges_New()
    Dim nRange          As Name
    Dim strName         As String
    Dim ans As Long
For Each nRange In ActiveWorkbook.Names
    strName = nRange.Name
    With ActiveWorkbook.Names.Item(strName)
    ans = Range(strName).Columns.Count
        
        .RefersTo = .RefersToRange.Resize(, ans + 12)
    
    End With
Next nRange
End Sub
```

1. When I ran this Macro, it gave me error '400'
2. When I press 'F8', both 'nRange' and 'strName' are showing 'File Name' (The current file name) on mouse over.
3. After the 'For' statement, The strName on mouse shows the error "
4. I have tried by pasting the above code in a new module as well as in the active sheet as well, but in vain.

Can you please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Please also post what error you are getting.

Comment: Hi Nazim, the original error message is 'Run-time error '449' "Argument not optional". When I go to Debug, the error is showing on line "Set xName = xWb.Names.Item".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dears,

For all those who are experiencing same issue, I was able to resolve it by the following macro:

```
Sub MonthlyReporting()
    Dim nRange          As Name
    Dim strName         As String
    Dim ans As Long
  
For Each nRange In ActiveWorkbook.Names
On Error Resume Next
    strName = nRange.Name
    With ActiveWorkbook.Names.Item(strName)
    ans = Range(strName).Columns.Count
        
        .RefersToR1C1 = .RefersToRange.Resize(, ans + 12)
    End With
Next nRange

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error is in this line:

```
Set xName = xWb.Names.Item
```

`item` needs an argument, so you should write:

```
Set xName = xWb.Names.Item(1)
```

or similar.

Although the documentation says the parameters are optional, later, in Remarks, it adds:

> You must specify one, and only one, of these three arguments.

The rest of your code works fine!

Ref:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.names.item

Comment: Hi JMP, Thanks for your time, I have added (1) as you suggested, however, it still gives a runtime error 1004 on the line ".RefersTo = .RefersToRange.Resize(, 14)" and when I go to debug, the error reads ".RefersToRange.Resize(, 14) = <Application-defined or object-defined error>